How do I renew a cert used for SSO/SAML (with EntraID/Azure as the identity provider)?
We have a cert renewing soon and I can't seem to find an answer online anywhere on how to renew it. There are plenty of tutorials on the initial setup but that's obviously already complete. It's been a year since this was setup so obviously my memory of it's setup is a bit hazy, as Salesforce isn't something I typically log into.
I can see there is a self-signed cert in Salesforce when I go to 'Certificate and Key Management' and that cert is defined in the Single Sign On Settings page for the 365 integration under the "Request Signing Certificate" field.
In the Azure Enterprise App for the SSO integration, under Single Sign On, I can see under SAML Certificates a "Token Signing Certificate" is expiring soon as well.
I'm just curious which end I need to update (or both?) and the proper steps to do so.
Thanks!
